# Showing both objects when click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i got a problem that when I want to show one article, it opens both!

```
<span class='pres'><img src='http://files.appcheck.se/icons/minecraft.png' /></span><span class='info'><a href='/minecraft' class='title'/><strong>Minecraft</strong></a><span id='cat'>Spel</span><br />Minecraft, ett spel där många lever sig in i dess stora och häpnandsväckande värld. 
Det är en gigantisk värld uppbyggd av fyrkan<span class='readmore 14'><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Läs mer</a></span><span class='more 14'>tiga block som du hugga/hacka/gräva bort och bygga fantastiska hus och monement med, men se upp så att nått monster hoppar på dig.</span><div class='clear'></div></div>
</div>
<script>
$(".readmore a").click(function () {
$(this).remove();
$(".more").show(this);
});
</script>
```

When Click on one of the readmore links, every .more on the pages showes up

Help?

Comment: How can you identify what `.more` do you want to show ?

Comment: You've got multiple `.more` elements selections that match. You need to unique identify the one you want, or just a related selector, such as `nearest`, etc.

Comment: Please post more of your HTML

Comment: How can i set unique id on each .more?

Comment: `<span id="more1" class='more'>`, `<span id="more2" class='more'>`, etc

Comment: Yea I understand that, but how can i make jquery understand if i just tell it to show .more when link is clicked?

Comment: It depends on the structure of your HTML. I see you've posted an update, let me see if I can make sense of it.

Comment: http://beta.appcheck.se/results.php?search=spel there's a demo of what i try to do but not sucess ( hit the link that is blue for see )

Comment: Remember to wrap your code in document.ready, not that it would matter much if the JS comes after the HTML; but just as a good practice anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
$('.readmore a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next().show();
});
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/UeqTe/)

or use `toggle` if you want to hide when click again.

```
$('.readmore a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next().toggle();
});
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/UeqTe/1/)

**Update**: Remove link afte click

```
$('.readmore a').click(function() {
    var $link = $(this);
    $link.parent().next().toggle();
    $link.remove();
});
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/UeqTe/3/)

Comment: Won't work, because it's ment to they can open every .more if they want, but with the code u wrote nothing happen!

Comment: @Laynus No problem, I'm glad to help you and welcome to SO. :)